# How to get an .MP4 Play Length with .NET (C#) or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I need the play length value from .MP4 files that are uploaded with RadAsyncUpload.

This Length value is seen when you right-click an .MP4 file and click the details tab.

How can this be accomplished inside a Web app? I imagine If it is possible with JavaScript I could pass the value to .Net or just use Telerik and .NET combined.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that easily in javascript. Follow the attached example. After getting that value from `javascript` post that time to serverside, and get that in serverside if you need there.

```js
function gettime() {
  var vid = document.getElementById("vid");
  alert(vid.duration);
}
```

```html
<video width="320" height="240" controls id="vid">
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
<br/>
<input type="button" value="Get Total Time" onclick="gettime();" />
```